# How to add metadata to the System.Type?

Tags: .net, reflection, f#

I've been working on a language, but in terms of .NET integration I've only managed to get primitive types working so far. Last night I had a good idea - instead of trying to figure out what the exact `System.Type` for tuples, modules and functions should be during typechecking, what I could do instead is get the `System.Type` of `System.Object` and add some metadata which corresponds to my own complex language types. What matters is not the exact `System.Type` I would be adding the metadata to, but that each of the stand-ins for the types in my language are distinct from each other.

The reason I need this is that I am using the functions from the reflection namespace for integration which involves juggling `System.Type`s.

```
type SpiralType =
    | IntT
    | StringT
    | TupleT of SpiralType list
```

As an example, what I would like to add to the `System.Type` would be the instances of the above F# discriminated union type in order to ensure uniqueness.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

A standard way of augmenting type information with extra data in .NET would be to use attributes, though attribute constructor arguments would normally be limited to values you can represent as literals. This may or might not be an issue for you, depending on how rich you would your metadata to be. DU's probably won't work.

Otherwise, a straightforward solution would be to wrap your value together with arbitrary metadata into a generic type, i.e.

```
type TypeWithMetadata<'typ, 'metadata>(value: 'typ, metadata: 'metadata) = 
    member this.Value = value
    member this.Metadata = metadata
```

though that might come with an overhead you'd want to avoid?

Comment: I know of this approach and am actively using it, but the reflection methods I am using for interop (`GetMethod`,`GetField`,`MakeGenericType`...) need to have `System.Type` passed in as arguments. My plan for if nobody gives me anything better is to inherit from `System.Type`, add an extra field to it that way and then upcasting at runtime to retrieve the relevant field. The overhead is no problem; it is just that I do not want to dive into the intricacies of `System.Type` unless I can't avoid it.

Comment: Though, I might be overthinking things and there is a way to do it as you suggest. I can't see it right now though.