# How to make a minimal useful implementation of a class that inherits from System.Type?

Tags: .net, reflection, f#

```
open System

type SpiralDU =
    | IntT
    | StringT
    | TupleT of SpiralDU list

type SpiralTypeToken(metadata: SpiralDU) =
    inherit Type()

    member val Metadata = metadata

    override __.IsDefined(a,b) = base.IsDefined(a,b)
    override __.GetCustomAttributes(a,b) = base.GetCustomAttributes(a,b)
    override __.GetCustomAttributes(a) = base.GetCustomAttributes(a)
    override __.GUID with get() = base.GUID
    override __.InvokeMember(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) = base.InvokeMember(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
    override __.Module with get() = base.Module
    override __.Assembly with get() = base.Assembly
    override __.Name with get() = base.Name
    override __.FullName with get() = base.FullName
    override __.Namespace with get() = base.Namespace
    override __.AssemblyQualifiedName with get() = base.AssemblyQualifiedName
    override __.BaseType with get() = base.BaseType
    override __.GetConstructorImpl(a,b,c,d,e) = base.GetConstructorImpl(a,b,c,d,e)
    override __.GetConstructors(a) = base.GetConstructors(a)
    override __.GetMethodImpl(a,b,c,d,e,f) = base.GetMethodImpl(a,b,c,d,e,f)
    override __.GetMethods(a) = base.GetMethods(a)
    override __.GetField(a,b) = base.GetField(a,b)
    override __.GetFields(a) = base.GetFields(a)
    override __.GetInterface(a,b) = base.GetInterface(a,b)
    override __.GetInterfaces() = base.GetInterfaces()
    override __.GetEvent(a,b) = base.GetEvent(a,b)
    override __.GetEvents(a) = base.GetEvents(a)
    override __.GetPropertyImpl(a,b,c,d,e,f) = base.GetPropertyImpl(a,b,c,d,e,f)
    override __.GetProperties(a) = base.GetProperties(a)
    override __.GetNestedType(a,b) = base.GetNestedType(a,b)
    override __.GetNestedTypes(a) = base.GetNestedTypes(a)
    override __.GetMembers(a) = base.GetMembers(a)
    override __.GetAttributeFlagsImpl() = base.GetAttributeFlagsImpl()
    override __.IsArrayImpl() = base.IsArrayImpl()
    override __.IsByRefImpl() = base.IsByRefImpl()
    override __.IsPointerImpl() = base.IsPointerImpl()
    override __.IsPrimitiveImpl() = base.IsPrimitiveImpl()
    override __.IsCOMObjectImpl() = base.IsCOMObjectImpl()
    override __.GetElementType() = base.GetElementType()
    override __.HasElementTypeImpl() = base.HasElementTypeImpl()
    override __.UnderlyingSystemType with get() = base.UnderlyingSystemType

open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Reflection
let x = Reflection.Assembly.Load("mscorlib")
let dic' = x.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2")

let key = TupleT [IntT; IntT]
let st = SpiralTypeToken(key) :> Type
let dic_ins_typ = dic'.MakeGenericType [|typeof<int>;typeof<int>|]
let dic_ins_typ' = dic'.MakeGenericType [|st;typeof<int>|]

dic_ins_typ.GetMethod("get_Item",[|typeof<int>|]) // Works
dic_ins_typ'.GetMethod("get_Item",[|st|]) // System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
```

This is related to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602208/how-to-add-metadata-to-the-system-type) of how to add metadata to the `System.Type`. What I would like it for `dic_ins_typ'` to work as well as `dic_ins_typ`, but I have no idea how to do this.

If anybody could point me to an example implementation of `System.Object`'s underlying `System.Type` or any else for that matter, I could probably make it on my own. Thanks.

Comment: `System.Type` is more like an interface than a class. It presents a surface against which consumers can program. It doesn't provide any implementation. This means that all your redirects to `base` don't accomplish anything. The most full implementation of this interface is `System.RuntimeType`.

Comment: Well, I figured as much. I am looking at the [`System.RuntimeType`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/rttype.cs)'s source and it is 6.1k LOCs long. I really just need only enough so I can substitute the token type for the generic parameters. Can this be done somehow?

Comment: The concept of "only enough" really depends on how it's going to be consumed. Figure out which methods will be called and implement those. On the other hand, if by "only enough" you mean "indistinguishable from RuntimeType", then you _do_ need the 6K LOC, no way around it.