# How to get the methods of a GenericInstanceType?

Tags: f#, mono.cecil

```
open System
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
open Mono.Cecil
open Mono.Cecil.Rocks

type SpiralType =
    | IntT
    | StringT
    | TupleT of SpiralType list

let module_ = ModuleDefinition.CreateModule("TypeTokenFactory",ModuleKind.Console)
let r1 = module_.ImportReference(typeof<obj>)
let r2 = module_.ImportReference(typeof<obj>)

let table = ConditionalWeakTable()
table.Add(r1,IntT)
table.Add(r2,StringT)

let mscorlib_path = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
let mscorlib = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(mscorlib_path)

let dictionary_type =
    mscorlib.Modules.[0].Types
    |> Seq.find (fun x -> x.Name = "Dictionary`2")

let dict_ins = dictionary_type.MakeGenericInstanceType([|r1;r2|])
// Lacks the Methods field...
```

I've long been trying to figure out how make the above work with `System.Type`, but now I am trying to do it with `Mono.Cecil`. For a bit of history on what I am trying to do, take a look at my last [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602208/how-to-add-metadata-to-the-system-type) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652587/how-to-make-a-minimal-useful-implementation-of-a-class-that-inherits-from-system) here on SO and the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3723) I opened on the F# repo that goes into it in great depth.

Let me summarize it shortly here: For the sake of integration with the language I am making, I need to be able to query the .NET assemblies for their types and do substitution of generic parameters for both classes and the methods.

Now, I do not need exact types to be substituted. As the example above shows, attaching metadata to a dummy type would be quite enough for my purposes, but now I have the problem in that unlike with `System.Type`, once I substitute the generic parameters I am no longer able to query the methods on the type.

So close. Is there any way to make this work with `Mono.Cecil`? Alternatively, I'd appreciate knowing if it would be possible with some other library. I do not need Cecil's assembly editing abilities at all for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cecil provides you with a relatively low level view of the metadata.

Cecil will provide you with ways to represent the different metadata constructs in an assembly, but not with the runtime representation of the types.

To answer your question, it won't tell you the methods of an instantiated generic type as this is a runtime construction, not something available from the metadata.

Higher level APIs like System.Reflection or IKVM.Reflection will do that.

Comment: I don't think he actually wants the "the methods of an instantiated generic type", actually I feel like he just wants a list of methods and the types still with the generic parameter in place - basically a meta view of the type (so he can replace those by it's internal handle later when generating code).

But this use case should be possible to do with Cecil, correct?

Comment: This is true, though since Cecil does not instantiate anything at runtime, I thought that much was clear from the context for my question. It is kind of confusing to describe this stuff since you have various stripes of types all floating around on the term level and intermingling.

Comment: @matthid correct, if you have a `GenericInstance`, its `ElementType` property will tell you the TypeReference from which the instance was constructed. Call `Resolve()` on it to get its `TypeDefinition`, and you can browse the methods. Only they will not be in the context of the generic instance.